# Sum of top 5 elements in NHibernate Linq

Tags: sql, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I want to receive sum of property in top 5 elements in linq to NHibernate query. If I use below code:

```
Session.Query<Document>().Take(5).Sum(x => x.Value)
```

I get 'method not supported' exception.

Any ideas?

NHibernate 3.3.1.4000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Session.Query<Document>().Select(x => x.Value).Take(5).Sum();
```

NHibernate only supports the `Sum` overload without an expression parameter.

And for unknown reasons you have to first `Select` and than `Take` as you correctly commented.

Comment: Thanks, but this also gives an exception.

Comment: You are right with the Sum overload. In your answer you have to change Take and Select methods order.

Comment: @ChrisJ: Indeed. That's strange, it shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the [nhibernate](/questions/tagged/nhibernate) [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) provider isn't fully implemented yet. Try to materialise using `.ToArray()` to memory and then calculate `.Sum()` using linq-to-memory.

For example:

```
Session.Query<Document>().Select(x => x.Value).Take(5).ToArray().Sum()
```

ps: same kind of problems could happens with `.Skip()` and joins with `DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: Transferring the data to the server and then summing will be less efficient. The summing can be done in DB as mentioned in Daniel Hilgarth's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `NHibernate.4.0.2.4000` the Sum with lambda works also `Session.Query<Document>().Take(5).Sum(x => x.Value)`.

If it is possible to get no rows returned and Value is not a nullable type you need to cast it to a nullable type as the sum will return null when no items are present:

```
Session.Query<Document>().Take(5).Sum(x => (decimal?)x.Value) ?? 0;
```